# Copying File From Gitlab To EC2 (/www/html) Folder Using Ssh

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2, ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am trying to copy files from my GitLab repository to the folder of my ec2 instance over ssh using `server_ip` and `ec2` private_key.
I am not able to copy my files into the target folder.

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```sh
stages:
  - deploy

deploy:

  stage: deploy
  image: alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add openssh-client
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add -
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
    - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  script:
    - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@$DEPLOY_SERVER 'rm -rf /var/www/html/*'
    - scp -r . ubuntu@$DEPLOY_SERVER:/var/www/html **
    ## Here How Can I Copy all my repositroy file to target folder**
```

Answer (score 0):

Check first the ssh call just before scp actually works.

Then try:

```
scp -o LogLevel=DEBUG -r . ubuntu@$DEPLOY_SERVER:/var/www/html
```

That will give you an idea why the scp fails, while the ssh call, I presume, works.